# Connect to database and export to sql script

Tags: java, database, import, export

I am looking for some way to connect to a MySQL database and export the structure and data into an SQL script that I could run again to import the data.

I am trying to do this using Java but have had no luck finding anything other than hibernates SchemaExport tool which I can't use because I do not have access to the hibernate cfg file.

Can anyone recommend any other tools or methods of doing this using Java?

Thanks

Edit:

```
 AnnotationConfiguration cfg = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure( "hibernate.cfg.xml" );
    SchemaExport schemaExport = new SchemaExport( cfg );
    schemaExport.setOutputFile( destination );
    schemaExport.setFormat( format );
    schemaExport.execute( true, false, false, create );
```

The above code is what I have tried to do using SchemaExport that comes with hibernate, but I do not have access to hibernate.cfg.xml.

Comment: If you're asking for tools, try at: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @kenorb Thanks for replying. By tool I meant something like a library that provided that functionality. Maybe tool isnt the right word.

Comment: Tool or library, it's the same and it would lead to poor quality answer with only links to the libraries. See: [Why are library recommendation questions prohibited?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134914/191655)

Comment: If you've more programming oriented question, then you've to paste your code or what you've tried so far, in other words show some effort.

Comment: @kenorb I already said what I tried before in the question and it didnt work. I can't think of any other way to do it, but ill post the code anyway if thats what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend doing this using Java, but with 'mysqldump' tool (provided with MySQL) instead ([more info on mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)).

Anyway, if you really want to do this with java, you can invoke 'mysqldump' in Java with `Runtime().getRuntime().exec("...")`, or preferably with some libraries like [Apache Commons Exec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/).